# Trouble summing results of an array - trying .inject, .sum but no avail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to sum the total discount a customer of my store will receive. I can successfully loop each row (product) savings against the RRP using the below code, however I am trying to sum the total of the new table column that's displayed in my view...

```
<% total = ((product_sums[product.id]-product.trans.average(:price))*product_qty[product.id]) %>

<td><%= total %></td>
```

I have tried to use;

```
total.inject(:+)

total.inject{|sum, x| sum + x}
```

and

```
.sum(:price)
```

But each time I receive the same error;

```
undefined method `inject' for #<BigDecimal...
```

Could someone please briefly point where I am going wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: it seems that your 'total' is already a decimal, just check its value.

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back, what do you mean? (newbie to Ruby and Rails).

I am looking to sum/add all of the results of the array, is this what you mean?

Comment: it seems that your  total is already a decimal when you call inject here: `total.inject(:+)`  What youre propably doing right now: (2.0).inject(:+)

Comment: Ah OK, so how would I sum all the decimals in the loop to give me the total figure? That's the part I'm confused about

Comment: you didnt provide all the code you got regarding this total variable so i can only assume that you should not loop through collection at all, .sum(:your_column_name) (`your_collection_name.sum(:your_column_name`)on collection, this way database will do the job for you (like 99% of time if database can do stuff for you, let it do so, this is what its made for) http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum

Comment: Thanks again - I'll try this. Does it matter that the 'column' on the table I'm creating is actually the result of a calculation on 2 columns (price paid - RRP)?

Comment: Found it! I'll post as an answer what I did, but thank you ever so much - pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments above for context, the answer was far simpler than the overcomplicated way I was trying to tackle it.

I simply used the following...

```
<% total_savings = @buyer.trans.average(:price)*@buyer.trans.sum(:quantity) %>

<strong>Total savings</strong> - £<%= total_savings %>
```

Comment: in my opinion you should most of the time avoid keeping your logic in views:
`@average_price = @buyer.trans.average(:price)` and `@quantity = *@buyer.trans.sum(:quantity)` then just use `@average_price` and `@quantity` in your views. Not sure how the rest of the logic look like, but you might even move most of it to the model. This way youll be able to get the data you need from any place of the app you want with as little code repetition as possible. I assume you might wanna see this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes regarding your .trans method/scope.